# Was "Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D." planned after "The Avengers"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, agents-of-shield

In *The Avengers* we know a certain character was killed (really, dead):

> Agent Phil Coulson

Then this character is brought back (alive again) in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, through a project later revealed as Tahiti.

Was the series planned before writing this character's death? Was it planned that he would come back in a TV series? Or did they just use it after-the-fact to make a new series? Or aside from all that, was it just a coincidence, and they had to write it into the series later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They did have plans before the film released but they didn't get the green-light until *Item 47* came with home media release of *The Avengers*.

> After the Coulson shorts helped video sales, D’Esposito wanted to make longer films — and he got his wish when Winderbaum and writer Eric Pearson (who scripted the first four shorts) pitched a Bonnie and Clyde-esque tale of a couple who use a discarded Chitauri weapon to rob banks and go on the run from S.H.I.E.L.D. “I was reading through a lot of pitches,” D’Esposito says, adding that scrapped ideas include shorts about a young Nick Fury and Maria Hill. “I gravitated toward this one immediately.” Disney CEO Bob Iger did too; after watching Item 47, he greenlit a series about the agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. . - [EW.com](https://ew.com/movies/2018/04/26/marvel-one-shots-oral-history-agent-carter-agents-of-shield/)

But a TV show with Coulson was discussed before the film came:

> “We all love Clark Gregg, there’s no doubt about that,” Whedon said. “From before we made ‘The Avengers,’ we discussed whether there was a way for him to be a part of the Marvel Universe, perhaps a part of a TV show even after his death. … The fact of the matter is, as much as we love him, now that I’m really running Marvel, I like to keep a type of artistic integrity, which means we don’t stretch the bounds of reality.”
>
> “There was never going to be a ‘S.H.I.E.L.D.’ show without Agent Phil Coulson!” said Feige - [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/nycc-coulson-lives-in-whedons-s-h-i-e-l-d-updated-with-photos/)

So they didn't know if show will come or not when they filmed *The Avengers* but they wanted to have Coulson from the start and that's why they revived him for the show.